# out of memory on a byte allocation, asynctask 5

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to load images from "url" which is the folder in my sd card that contains about 40 images into my reader but I keep getting the out of memory error. is there anyway to solve it? could it be because im trying to load 40 images at one go thats why it is causing an error?

Below is my logcat output

```
02-01 15:38:17.410: D/url(10695): /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.sfa.coverflow/Issues/20/1944628064
02-01 15:38:17.440: D/dalvikvm(10695): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7144K, 32% free 16978K/24711K, paused 23ms
02-01 15:38:17.440: I/dalvikvm-heap(10695): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 33033616-byte allocation
02-01 15:38:17.460: D/dalvikvm(10695): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 32% free 16969K/24711K, paused 25ms
02-01 15:38:17.460: E/dalvikvm-heap(10695): Out of memory on a 33033616-byte allocation.
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695): "AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=17 RUNNABLE
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x411358f0 self=0x468d20
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   | sysTid=10718 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3779488
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   | schedstat=( 48743000 7345000 28 ) utm=4 stm=0 core=1
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:324)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at com.sfa.touchview.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:108)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at com.sfa.touchview.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:1)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-01 15:38:17.460: I/dalvikvm(10695):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-01 15:38:17.460: D/skia(10695): --- decoder->decode returned false
02-01 15:38:17.470: W/dalvikvm(10695): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4f1f8)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:324)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at com.sfa.touchview.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:108)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at com.sfa.touchview.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:1)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-01 15:38:17.470: E/AndroidRuntime(10695):    ... 4 more
```

this is where the error occurs

```
public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>
    {
        //RETRIEVES LINK FROM GALLERYACTIVITY
        //READ MNT/SDCARD/....

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            bm = null;
            String url = strings[0];
            Log.d("url",url);

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
            return bm;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use The Below code to resize your bitmap.

For Example if your a loadion a image with resoultion 1200 *800 in a view of  300 * 300

you can use `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResource(),R.drawable.mImage,300,300)`
To reduce memory utilization.

```
/**
     * 
     * get a resized bitmap
     * @param bm
     * @param newHeight
     * @param newWidth
     * @return
     */
    public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bitmap
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // "recreate" the new bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Decode a bitmap for avoiding out of memory issue
     * @param res
     * @param resId
     * @param reqWidth
     * @param reqHeight
     * @return
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);
        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, how do i exactly implement the code? Sorry, i am not very good at programming

Comment: Hi, i have implemented your codes and did mImageView.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(bm, 700, 500)); but i still get the same error :(

Comment: No you should use decodeSampledBitmapResource  not getResizedBitmap If you are still having the same issue try reduceing the size of the bitmap for example decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResource(),R.drawable.mImage,100,100)